# Dynamically change text e.g. translate in html document with css only?

Tags: html, css

I like the google translate button, can I hack the functionality into an html email document using html and css only?

I'd like to have a drop-down at the top like [English | Spanish | Chinese] and then present the body text in the chosen language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't achieve this only by HTML and CSS. Need some kind scripting...

Answer (score 1):

Best I can think of is to build your email with the content of all three languages in the body and then rely on the `<details>` and `<summary>` tags to open/close the chosen language. You can then use CSS to style detail tags into something like the google translate button.

Its a long shot though. What you describe requires JavaScript, specially if you want the content to change dynamically instead of showing/hiding it.

Comment: looks like a good idea but it just shows up fully open and nothing to click

Comment: that's too bad, perhaps those tags aren't supported by email clients